# jquery-sortable using behavior of a linkedlist

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, collections, jquery-ui-sortable

I suspect I'm not looking at this issue in the right way so here goes.

I have essentially a LinkedList of data on a web page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) that I'd like to manipulate using traditional Linked List behavior (i.e. just updating the reference/id of the "next" object) for performance reasons.

Where this gets a bit tricky is I'd ideally like to use Jquery's sortable to do this.  Like the user would drag something up/down and I could just do an Ajax call to the server with the id of the object that moved and the new parent id of that object (and then behind the scenes I could figure out how to reconnect things..maybe need more data than that...).

But every example I've seen where sortable is used they were sending the whole re-indexed list to the database to update which seems unnecessary to me.  With a linked list to change an element's "index" I only need to make 3 updates which depending on the size of the list could be a big performance savings. Anyone have an example of what I'm trying to do...am I too far in left field?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by hooking onto the 'start' and 'update' events on sortable to figure out which item had moved to where, and then only sending that index to the server.

```
var items;

$('ul#sortable').sortable({
    start: function() {
        items = $('li.item:not(.ui-sortable-placeholder)', this);
    },
    update: function() {
        $('li.item:not(.ui-sortable-placeholder)', this).each(function(i) {
            var order = items.index(this);
            if (order > i + 1 || order < i) {
                // do ajax request here
                console.log('item %d was moved to %d', order, i);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The result was used to reorder a list stored on the server, which in Python is as simple as

```
items.insert(index2, items.pop(index1))
```